# can I set autocommit to ON while using savepoints

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, transactions

I am a newbiee to Java database programming.
Recently during my project, I have got stuck in a concept, which I searched a lot but not getting any solution to satisfy my query, which may help me to get out of my problem.

Actually the problem is:

I have three table, let say one main (which contains common fields of actual data) table and two child table(which contains other different fields according to some criteria). Main table contain some part of information, and rest of information, depending on some criteria, will be saved in only one of the child table.

Now the scenario is like this, I have set autocommit off, then firing one insert query. So, when the insert query will be fired, database will give it a unique ID, in mysql, since the ID feild is autoIncrement. Now firing a Select Query, I want to extract that ID from main table. So, here is my question, **Will SELECT QUERY BE ABLE TO EXTRACT THE ID OF THAT PARTICLULAR RECORD I HAVE JUST SAVED?** Please remember that autocommit is set to false, and I have not committed yet.

I am doing this because I want that unique ID to be inserted in one of the child tables so that I can relate the information between table. So, After finding the ID, I have again fired a new INSERT query to save rest of the data in one of the child tables, now with the unique ID with rest of the data. And then on successful insertion, I have committed the connection.

Also, I want that either the information is saved in both (main and one of the child) tables or the details does not saves completely if any failure occur, so that I do not lose the partial information.

Please Help me in this. If you can explain what is relation between autocommit, savepoints. When to use, what things are to be remembered. Please provide some genuine resources, if you can, which demonstrate their nature,how they work under different circumstances, etc. I have googled but didn't got any such useful information. I want to get deep knowledge about it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to get the ID when the record is added to the table. This is available when you insert the record if you use the getGeneratedKeys(). The autocommit cannot be used to return this.

The following code shows how this can be done.

```
/**
 * Insert to database using JDBC 3.0 + which will return the key of the new row.
 * 
 * @param sql is the sql insert to send to the database
 * @return the key for the inserted row
 * @throws DBSQLException
 */
public static int insertAndReturnKey(Connection dbConnection, String sql, List<SqlField> params) throws DBSQLException
{

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String paramList = null;
    try {
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        // Setup your parameters
        int result = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            return (resultSet.getInt(1));
        } else {
            // throw an exception from here
            throw new SQLException("Failed to get GeneratedKey for [" + sql + "]");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new DBSQLException(buildErrorMessage(ex, sql, params));
    } finally {
        DBConnector.closeQuietly(preparedStatement);
        DBConnector.closeQuietly(resultSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you sir. Now I am getting some hope for the solution about my problem.I am facing one problem, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS giving error, in netbeans, It is saying _cannot find symbol_. Please help

Comment: I got It sir. Actually since we are using Prepared Statmemts. So, We will be using **PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);** instead of **PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);**. Thank you sir, It helped a lot.